# An error was returned while trying to install the kernel into the target system

Tags: kernel, kali-linux, virtualbox, system-installation

[image]

I tried reinstalling Oracle Virtual Box and Tried re downloading ISO again but it didnt fix this error.
I am new to linux so i barely know about this error.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when trying to install Kali on a VM with a 2GB hard drive. I increased the hard drive to 4GB and got a little further in the install then another error during the select and install software stage.  5GB also wasn't enough.

At this point I made the drive 20GB and it worked. So you need somewhere between 5 to 20GB hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Got here via google search.
Another possible reason when using preseed file (for example in packer):
The preseed file has errors in the partman-section, so there's no drive available.